# Downgrade Android Plugin in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've got two workstations with Android Studio installed. The first one is having version 2.3.3, but the other one is having version 3.0. Both of them are using Gradle 3.3. The problem that I am facing is that when I create an application on the 3.0 system and then transfer it to the 2.3.3 it doesn't want to build. I am receiving

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. 
>    > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0.
>        Searched in the following locations:
>        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom
>        https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.jar

I compared a build.gradle file created from the older version of Android Studio and from the newer version

3.0 version:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0
}
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

2.3.3:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

From the 3.0 version, I removed "google()", because it was also failing.

I am new to Android Development and I would really appreciate it if you can help me to solve my problem of using one project on both of the environments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'. > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0. Searched in the following locations: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.0.0/gradle-3.0.0.pom

**It happens because you are using the wrong repository.**

If you want to use **android plugin for gradle 3.x** you have to use:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
        // You need to add the following repository to download the
        // new plugin.
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    }
}
```

It requires also **gradle v4.+** using in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` :

```
distributionUrl=\
  https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

If you are using **Android Studio 2.x** you have to change the repository `google()` with  `maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }`

If you want to use the android plugin for gradle 2.3.x you can use:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}
```

and you can use gradle v.3.3 with:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Of course in this case **you can't** use the new DSL introduced with gradle v.4.x and the plugin 3.x for example the `implementation()` and `api()` DSL.

Comment: What I did is in build.gradle I set dependencies {classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'} and in gradle-wrapper.properties i set distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip. But now I am receiving :  

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not find method implementation() for arguments [directory 'libs'] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: compile is deprecated now you should use implementation in above 3.0

Comment: @Avtontom You can't use the implementation() DSL if you are using the gradle plugin 2.3.3 since it was introduced with gradle 4.x and gradle plugin 3.x

Comment: ok, so how can I remove that implementation(). My main aim is to configure my 3.0 Android Studio, so the projects I create there won't fail on my university PC's because I can't upgrade the university PC to gradle 4.x

Comment: if you use gradle plugin 2.3 you have to use `compile` instead of `api` or `implementation`.

Answer (score 1):

Android plugin 3.0 located in Google Maven Repository (`google()` line) and it requires new Gradle. You should update Gradle to version 4.1.

Open file `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` and set

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **android studio <3.0** then go to gradle-wrapper.properties and change the gradle from `4.1` to `3.3`.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Go to top level gradle and change the gradle version from `3.0.0` to `2.3.3` and then it should work fine.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

If you are using **android studio >3.0** then Go to gradle-wrapper.properties and change the gradle to `4.1`.

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.3-all.zip
```

Go to top level gradle and change the gradle version from `3.0.0` and then it should work fine.

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```