# android studio, fix Android caching problems

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

Please help, just updated Android Studio, and build will not complete/sync

error message:
Gradle sync failed: Android plugin 3.1.2 is not supported by Android cache fix plugin. Supported Android plugin versions: 3.1.0-alpha09, 3.0.0, 3.0.1. Override with -Dorg.gradle.android.cache-fix.ignoreVersionCheck=true.
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (616ms)

Comment: Please help me with this question or show me how to override.

Answer (score 2):

It would be fixed soon!!
Following is the workaround for now -

You can add `systemProp.org.gradle.android.cache-fix.ignoreVersionCheck=true` in your `gradle.properties` file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, try to downgrade

> Android plugin 3.1.2

to

> 3.1.0-alpha09

try take a look 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47093055/downgrade-android-plugin-in-android-studio)